# Path counting in a grid - what's the way to prove this approach?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I was recently watching [a video on Khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/math-for-fun-and-glory/puzzles/brain-teasers/v/path-counting-brain-teaser), where he works through a problem about finding all possible paths in an n X n grid from the top left position to the bottom right position, by only going down or right.

Basically the approach he takes is based on using pascals triangle and counting the ways to reach at a certain position and add them to the number of ways so far.

I got interested in this and tried to generalize a formula for finding the amount of possible paths in a n X m grid.

My idea is as follows: Let's assume a 2 x 3 grid. We start at the top left and need to go to the bottom right (assuming we can only move right/dow). One possible path would be

1. down
2. down
3. right
4. right
5. right

As it turns out, all possible paths in a 2 x 3 grid will have a length of n + m = 5 in this case.

If we see moving through the grid as a kind of series of commands (down/right), we can find all possible permutations of down/right by computing $(n + m)!$ For example, in the 2 x 3 grid we compute $5!$, that would give us all possible permutations of

1. down 1
2. down 2
3. right 1
4. right 2
5. right 3

However, that would also count down2, down1, ... as  valid combination, which it's not, you can go at most 2 times down, but you must start with down1 from the start position. The refined formula looks like this (to get unique combinations of commands):

$(n + m)! \div (n!m!$)

In a quadratic 5 x 5 grid, the above would evaluate to 252, in a 2 x 3 grid it would be 10 paths. From what I can see, that seems like a correct approach, at least from a few examples I tried.

My next step was to try to write a proof for this, I thought maybe a proof by induction would be possible? But my question question is, what is $n$ in this case (steps? grid size?) if I would like to write a proof for this? Or is induction not possible in this case?

Comment: I suspect you will want to make use of structural induction for this proof.

Comment: Induction is not the natural route here. Just realize that from $n+m$ steps exactly $n$ must get the label "down". There are $\binom{n+m}{n}$ ways to select $n$ from $n+m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this example meets your need.

Suppose that $3$ from the numbers in $\{1,\dots,5\}$ must be selected.

We can start with writing the numbers in all possible orders, and then pick the $3$ utmost left as the selected ones. There are $5!=120$ orders and we get something like:

- 123|45
- 123|54
- ...
- 543|21

Now observe that the e.g. the orders 12345 and 12354 both result in the selection 123.
Now wonder how many orders can be found that result in selection 123. For the order of numbers 1,2,3 there are $3!=6$ possibilities and for the order of the numbers 4,5 there are $2!=2$ possibilities. That means that the selection 123 is the result of $3!2!$ of the $5!$ arrangements. To repair this overcounting we divide by $3!2!$ and we end up with $\frac{5!}{3!2!}$ distinct selections.

Comment: Oh wow, now it clicked why I actually need the division. I just did in the outline of my formula because I remember that's what you do to "remove duplicates" but now it makes actually sense. Thanks! More formally speaking, since proof by induction is not applicable, would your explanation in this form accepeted as a "proof" (just asking, I'm really new and inexperienced).

Comment: Glad to help. This will be accepted as a "proof". Personally I would say: $n$ of the $m+n$ steps must be selected and there are $\binom{n+m}{n}=\frac{(n+m)!}{n!m!}$ ways to do that, period. That is in my view enough allready. If "they" want more, and ask how to get that then I would use this example to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Hints for your proof:

1. You have realised correctly, that every path from $(0, 0)$ through $(n, m)$ can be expressed as a permutation of $n$ `rights` and $m$ `lefts`.
2. However, what you've not got correct is that fact that all `rights` are *equivalent* and all `downs` are *equivalent* i.e. `down1` is the same as `down2`
3. In how many ways can you permute $m + n$ objects out of which $m$ are of one kind and $n$ are of another?